# Basic linear algebra doubt on Dimension of Vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $V(R)=M$ of order $2$

$$W_1=\left\{
    \begin{pmatrix}
     a & b \\
     0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
 : a ,b \in R\right\}$$

$$W_2=\left\{
    \begin{pmatrix}
     a & 0 \\
     c & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
 : a ,c \in R \right\}$$

$$W_1+W_2=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
     2a & b \\
     c & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
 : a ,b,c \in R\right\}$$

I am trying to find out the dimension of $W_1+W_2$ using the definition: The number of elements in the basis for  $V$ is called dimension of $V$.

Now we have vectors $v_1=(2a,c),v_2=(b,0)$

both are linearly independent and each have two elements in it so dimension is $2$. Is this the  correct way to find dimension ?

Comment: For $W_i$, do you intend to type them in set notation but having difficulty displaying them?

Comment: What is $W_2 $?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I didnt 't get you. I am just unable to find dimension.

Comment: @Bernard typo check now

Comment: is $W_1$ a subspace? or a particular matrix? what do you mean by dimension of a particular matrix if it is a particular matrix?

Comment: Now, if $W_1+W_2ˆ$ is the sum of two subspaces, you shouldn't have $2a$ in the upper left corner, because  the $a$ in particular instances of vectors in the subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ are not necessarily the same.

Comment: @Bernard So i have taken the case where a=a ? Which will not be always true ?

Comment: You should have written $a$, not $2a$, since there are quantifiers behing the definition of a set. In detail: for particular instances , the sum should yield something like $a+a'$, which you eventually denote $a$, due to the implicit quantifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \right\}$$

is a basis for $W_1+W_2$.

Hopefully you can state the dimension correctly.

The question is not talking about column space of a particular matrix.

Comment: oh so  I was calculated column space which $2$ here.

Answer (score 2):

Note that$$W_1+W_2=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a+a'&b\\c&0\end{pmatrix}\,\middle|\,a,a',b,c\in\mathbb{R}\right\}.$$It's dimension is three, because$$W_1+W_2=\operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$and the previous set is linearly independent.

Comment: What does previous set is linearly independent means ?

Comment: Why it is $a+a^{'}$ not $2a$

Comment: It means that$$a\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\iff a=b=c=0.$$

Comment: Because the $a$ from an element of $W_1$ doesn't have to be the same $a$ that was used in an element of $W_2$.